# Remove first two valid data points from time series data in wide format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]I have data where each row as customers and what is the quantity they bought. There are 12 columns in the data starting from Jan 2018 to Dec 2018 (each column is a month).

Let us say for customer X1, my data starts in June 2018 so first 5 columns of this row are empty.
For customer X2, my data starts in Aug 2018 so first 7 columns of this row are empty.
For customer X3, my data starts in Jan 2018 so all of the columns have data points.
For each of the row (i.e.) every customer, I want to delete the first 2 data points and make them null. Red color indicates null values.

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Jan-18': [np.nan, np.nan, 15],
                   'Feb-18': [np.nan, np.nan, 20],
                   'Mar-18': [np.nan, np.nan, 15],
                   'Apr-18': [np.nan, np.nan, 20],
                   'May-18': [np.nan, np.nan, 15],
                   'Jun-18': [2, np.nan, 20],
                   'Jul-18': [5, np.nan, 15],
                   'Aug-18': [10, 10, 20],
                   'Sep-18': [15, np.nan, 15],
                   'Oct-18': [20, 15, 20],
                   'Nov-18': [25, 20, 15],
                   'Dec-18': [30, 20, 20]})
    
    output_df = pd.DataFrame({'Jan-18': [np.nan, np.nan, 15],
                   'Feb-18': [np.nan, np.nan, 20],
                   'Mar-18': [np.nan, np.nan, 15],
                   'Apr-18': [np.nan, np.nan, 20],
                   'May-18': [np.nan, np.nan, 15],
                   'Jun-18': [np.nan, np.nan, 20],
                   'Jul-18': [np.nan, np.nan, 15],
                   'Aug-18': [10, np.nan, 20],
                   'Sep-18': [15, np.nan, 15],
                   'Oct-18': [20, np.nan, 20],
                   'Nov-18': [25, 20, 15],
                   'Dec-18': [30, 20, 20]})
```

So for X1, I delete June and July (both were valid data points i.e. not null) and data will start from August.

For X2, I delete August, there was no data for Sept, but there is data for Oct. So, I have to delete both August and Oct.

For X3, since I dont know when exactly in past it became my customer, I dont want to delete anything. [I can calculate count for every row and filter rows with count 12 so no deletion happens there]

I have thought about using count and shape to find number of null values in every row. `df.shape[1] - df.count(axis=1)`
But not sure how to delete the first 2 data points in every row. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: IMHO, this is just too much text. Can you provide your sample data and expected output in the table form (in text, not pictures)?

Comment: @QuangHoang done

Answer (score 0):

```
# script (after using the provided code to generate `df`):  
x, y = np.nonzero(df.notnull().values)
loc = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y}).groupby('x').head(2)
xnull, ynull = zip(*loc.groupby('x').filter(lambda p: list(p.y) != [0, 1]).values)
df.iloc[list(xnull), list(ynull)] = np.nan
```

- first the x & y index values are obtained for the dataframe having non-null values.
- for each x coord, the first two y values are taken to form a dataframe `loc` with 6 rows.
- `loc` is filtered to remove rows if the y coords are 0 & 1, i.e the first non null values are found in the first two rows of the original dataframe
- the filtered locations are split into the x & y coordinates that will be set to null.
- the values in the dataframe are overwritten with null. note that this mutates the original dataframe, so if the original dataframe is required, ensure that a copy is made & modified instead.

notes:

- the filter would null-out the case where a customer made a purchase in the first or second month & never purchased again.
- `xnull` & `ynull` are initially tuples, which had to be converted to `list` to work with `iloc`. However `list(p.y)` is aggregating values in column `y` into a `list`